# JavaScript: position a dynamically created element so that "floats" over the page

Tags: javascript, floating

I have this table of classes given in certain classrooms at the various class periods in the day. Each table cell contains both the class title and the instructor's name.

The goal is to have a text "balloon" popup when the cursor hovers over either the class title or instructor's name. In the former case the text would be the class description and in the latter the instructor's bio. This material will be in the markup in `<div>`'s set to `display: none`. *Currently, only the first cell has such material.*

Ultimately, I want the balloon to "float" over the page and be "attached" to the cursor. It should self-dismiss on mouseout of the class title or instructor's name.

The effect I'm looking for can be seen by hovering over the word "block" in the first paragraph on [this page](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814528-Using-the-Image-Block). I've developed a reduced case at the pen [Popup Project Reduced Case](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/qZQMox). I've reproduced all the code below for your convenience.

I've gotten the JavaScript to the point where the balloon pops up correctly populated with the appropriate text.

But in positioning itself the popup pushes the table down by the amount of its height. This moves the element over which the cursor was hovering out from under the cursor thus realizing an involuntary mouseout. The popup is removed, the table repositions itself up, the element is back under the cursor and we have a mouseover. The popup pops up, the table gets pushed down, we have a mouseout, and so the war goes between the two events.

**So how do I position the popup with JavaScript so that it "floats" over the table rather than inserting itself above the table and pushing the table down?**

```js
/*
 ** JavaScript for Class Schedule popup project
 */
;

////  declare global variables  ////
var nodeObject;
var popup;

////  main routine ////
nodeObject = document.getElementsByClassName("class-title");
addListeners(nodeObject);
nodeObject = document.getElementsByClassName("instructor");
addListeners(nodeObject);



////  define functions  ////

function addListeners(nodeObject) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodeObject.length; i++) {
      nodeObject[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverElement);
      nodeObject[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutFromElement);
    } // end for
  } // end fn addListeners

function populatePopup(popup, event) {
    var popupHTMLTML;
    // populate the popup <div>
    popupHTML = event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML;
    popup.classList.add("popup");
    popup.style.display = "none";
    popup.innerHTML = popupHTML;
    return popup;
  } // end fn populatePopup

function showPopup(popup, parentNode, targetNodeID) {
    parentNode.insertBefore(popup, targetNodeID);
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } // end fn showPopup

function createElement(tag) {
    var newElement;
    newElement = document.createElement(tag);
    return newElement;
  } // end fn createElement

function mouseoverElement(event) {
    popup = createElement('div');
    popup = populatePopup(popup, event);
    showPopup(popup, ScheduleWrapper, ScheduleTable);
  } // end fn mouseoverElement

function mouseoutFromElement(event) {
    ScheduleWrapper.removeChild(popup);
  } // end fn mouseoutFromElement</code></pre>
```

```css
/* Class Schedule table */

.schedule-wrapper {} .schedule {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: .8em;
}
.schedule p {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.schedule th,
.schedule td {
  border: solid tan 1px;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.schedule th {
  text-align: center;
}
.schedule .header-row,
.schedule .header-col {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center
}
.schedule .header-col {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 125px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}
.class-title {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: left;
  color: blue;
}
.instructor {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: right;
  color: blue;
}
.class-descrip,
.instructor-bio {
  color: purple;
  display: none;
}
.class-title:hover + .class-descrip,
.instructor:hover + .instructor-bio {
  display: block;
}
.popup {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .schedule-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 0 0;
  }
  .schedule {
    width: auto;
  }
  .schedule th,
  .schedule td {
    max-width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ScheduleWrapper" class="schedule-wrapper">
  <table id="ScheduleTable" class="schedule">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header-row">
        <!--header row 1-->
        <th scope="col" class="header-col">classroom</th>
        <!--col 1-->
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <!--col 2-->
        <th scope="col">C</th>
        <!--col 3-->
        <th scope="col">D</th>
        <!--col 4-->
        <th scope="col">E</th>
        <!--col 5-->
        <th scope="col">F</th>
        <!--col 6-->
        <th scope="col">I</th>
        <!--col 7-->
      </tr>
      <tr class="header-row">
        <!--header row 2-->
        <th scope="col" class="header-col">capacity</th>
        <!--col 1-->
        <th scope="col">30</th>
        <!--col 2-->
        <th scope="col">50</th>
        <!--col 3-->
        <th scope="col">100</th>
        <!--col 4-->
        <th scope="col">30</th>
        <!--col 5-->
        <th scope="col">50</th>
        <!--col 6-->
        <th scope="col">100</th>
        <!--col 7-->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!--row 5-->
        <th scope="row" class="header-col">9:30 - 10:30</th>
        <!--header col 1, period 3-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Searching on Ancestry.com 2016 (Basic Search Ideas)
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
              Searching on Ancestry has changed drastically in 2016. Learn advanced syntax and searching strategies.
            </p>
            <p>This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet.
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            Mindy McLane
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
              Mindy McLane has taught courses at each of our conferences. She is particularly adept at all things Ancestry.
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 2-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Land and Title Records
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            Nancy Feroe
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 3-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Open Computer Lab
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            varying instructors
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 4-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            "Hey Dad! What did you do in the War?"
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            Jim Johnson
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 5-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Thinking through your DNA results and figuring out what to do next.
          </p>
          <p class="instructor">
            Dianne Gianninni Dianne Gianninni
            <div class="instructor-bio">
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 6-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title" ">
                  Come Find Out What’s Available at the Family History Center in Springdale
                  </p>
                  <div class="class-descrip "><p>
                  </p>
                  </div>
                  <p class="instructor ">
                  Charlie Fowler
                  </p>
                  </div>
                </td>         <!--col 7-->
      </tr>
      
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try `position: fixed` in the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] how do I position the popup with JavaScript so that it "floats" over the table rather than inserting itself above the table and pushing the table down?

You would use CSS's `position: absolute` and set at least two (2) of the following properties: `top, right, bottom, left` for your `.popup` class.

```js
/*
 ** JavaScript for Class Schedule popup project
 */
;

////  declare global variables  ////
var nodeObject;
var popup;

////  main routine ////
nodeObject = document.getElementsByClassName("class-title");
addListeners(nodeObject);
nodeObject = document.getElementsByClassName("instructor");
addListeners(nodeObject);



////  define functions  ////

function addListeners(nodeObject) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodeObject.length; i++) {
      nodeObject[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverElement);
      nodeObject[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutFromElement);
    } // end for
  } // end fn addListeners

function populatePopup(popup, event) {
    var popupHTMLTML;
    // populate the popup <div>
    popupHTML = event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML;
    popup.classList.add("popup");
    popup.style.display = "none";
    popup.innerHTML = popupHTML;
    return popup;
  } // end fn populatePopup

function showPopup(popup, parentNode, targetNodeID) {
    parentNode.insertBefore(popup, targetNodeID);
    popup.style.display = "block";

    // set these to whatever values you'd like to offset by
    popup.style.top = 0;
    popup.style.left = 0;
  } // end fn showPopup

function createElement(tag) {
    var newElement;
    newElement = document.createElement(tag);
    return newElement;
  } // end fn createElement

function mouseoverElement(event) {
    popup = createElement('div');
    popup = populatePopup(popup, event);
    showPopup(popup, ScheduleWrapper, ScheduleTable);
  } // end fn mouseoverElement

function mouseoutFromElement(event) {
    ScheduleWrapper.removeChild(popup);
  } // end fn mouseoutFromElement</code></pre>
```

```css
/* Class Schedule table */

.schedule-wrapper {} .schedule {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: .8em;
}
.schedule p {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.schedule th,
.schedule td {
  border: solid tan 1px;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.schedule th {
  text-align: center;
}
.schedule .header-row,
.schedule .header-col {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center
}
.schedule .header-col {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 125px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}
.class-title {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: left;
  color: blue;
}
.instructor {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: right;
  color: blue;
}
.class-descrip,
.instructor-bio {
  color: purple;
  display: none;
}
.class-title:hover + .class-descrip,
.instructor:hover + .instructor-bio {
  display: block;
}
.popup {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .schedule-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 0 0;
  }
  .schedule {
    width: auto;
  }
  .schedule th,
  .schedule td {
    max-width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ScheduleWrapper" class="schedule-wrapper">
  <table id="ScheduleTable" class="schedule">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header-row">
        <!--header row 1-->
        <th scope="col" class="header-col">classroom</th>
        <!--col 1-->
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <!--col 2-->
        <th scope="col">C</th>
        <!--col 3-->
        <th scope="col">D</th>
        <!--col 4-->
        <th scope="col">E</th>
        <!--col 5-->
        <th scope="col">F</th>
        <!--col 6-->
        <th scope="col">I</th>
        <!--col 7-->
      </tr>
      <tr class="header-row">
        <!--header row 2-->
        <th scope="col" class="header-col">capacity</th>
        <!--col 1-->
        <th scope="col">30</th>
        <!--col 2-->
        <th scope="col">50</th>
        <!--col 3-->
        <th scope="col">100</th>
        <!--col 4-->
        <th scope="col">30</th>
        <!--col 5-->
        <th scope="col">50</th>
        <!--col 6-->
        <th scope="col">100</th>
        <!--col 7-->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!--row 5-->
        <th scope="row" class="header-col">9:30 - 10:30</th>
        <!--header col 1, period 3-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Searching on Ancestry.com 2016 (Basic Search Ideas)
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
              Searching on Ancestry has changed drastically in 2016. Learn advanced syntax and searching strategies.
            </p>
            <p>This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet. This is some blah blah tet.
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            Mindy McLane
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
              Mindy McLane has taught courses at each of our conferences. She is particularly adept at all things Ancestry.
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 2-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Land and Title Records
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            Nancy Feroe
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 3-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Open Computer Lab
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            varying instructors
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 4-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            "Hey Dad! What did you do in the War?"
          </p>
          <div class="class-descrip">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p class="instructor">
            Jim Johnson
          </p>
          <div class="instructor-bio">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 5-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title">
            Thinking through your DNA results and figuring out what to do next.
          </p>
          <p class="instructor">
            Dianne Gianninni Dianne Gianninni
            <div class="instructor-bio">
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <!--col 6-->
        <td>
          <p class="class-title" ">
                  Come Find Out What’s Available at the Family History Center in Springdale
                  </p>
                  <div class="class-descrip "><p>
                  </p>
                  </div>
                  <p class="instructor ">
                  Charlie Fowler
                  </p>
                  </div>
                </td>         <!--col 7-->
      </tr>
      
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wonderful. Just perfect. Thanks ever so much. So much question for such a short, clean, neat solution. Not JavaScript after all but CSS. Guess I have to go back and read some more about the `position` property . Thanks again.